# Added variables to my path analysis model are significant predictors but model fit is worse?

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, lavaan, path-model

I want to test if there are additional moderation effects to my existing model. The moderation effects (variables are centered) are significant, but the model fit gets significantly worse (lavaan). Now I don't know, if I should include the moderations. How can these results be interpreted?

I have 600 observations

Fit of old model:

[image]

Fit of new model:

[image]

Comment: How did you measure model fit?  What is sample size?

Comment: These moderators were not in your model before in any way, I assume. If they weren't, it may be because the moderators have relations in the data with some variables, relations you have constrained to zero.

Comment: @user162986 I forgot to mention: the moderators are already in the model as mediators

Comment: Well, somehow, your degrees of freedom increased from 4 to 10. That means you constrained a lot of paths to zero. And somewhere in there, you may have model misspecification, assuming the software is working right.